# What is the use of objectApiName in lightning:recordViewForm

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-recordviewform

While exploring [Lightning Data Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service.htm), I came across another option to load record without apex/soql in Lightning components using [`lightning:recordViewForm`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordViewForm/documentation) tag, which works in conjunction with [`lightning:outputField`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:outputField/) to display specific fields of the record provided by `recordId` attribute.

There is another attribute of this component, `objectApiName` and the documentation only gives following information about the attribute

> The API name of the object. (this attribute is required)

Now, the fun part is, I just have to put this attribute in the component, no matter what `value` I provide against this attribute, the component is rendered successfully on the basis of the `recordId`. Few examples given below

**Examples-Component rendered successfully**

1. `<lightning:recordViewForm recordId="0066F00000kkQVfQAM" objectApiName="Opportunity">`
2. `<lightning:recordViewForm recordId="0066F00000kkQVfQAM" objectApiName="">`
3. `<lightning:recordViewForm recordId="0066F00000kkQVfQAM" objectApiName="garbage">`

Only case where the component is **not** rendered, when the `objectApiName` is not provided, which offcourse is required

`<lightning:recordViewForm recordId="0066F00000kkQVfQAM" >`

What is the purpose of `objectApiName` attribute if it has not impact on the outcome?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Purely speculation, but my guesses are:

- that there is a base component that `lightning:recordViewForm` extends that supports the "new" case where there is no Id and so the type needs to be known
- having the type up front is an optimisation compared with working out the type from the Id
- as the component evolved, the implementation did require it in early versions but not in later versions but the attribute has been left required

Comment: Sorry @Keith C for late acceptance. I was looking for an official response, I even tweeted this to Salesforce Devs but nothing came up. So, until an official response comes up, I am accepting yours as the best. :)

Comment: @Mahmood No problem and no need to accept it: just some guesses based on little...

Comment: No, I must say they are pretty good guesses. :)
So it is, so far, the best answer.