# lighting:recordEditForm error Cannot read property 'defaultRecordTypeId' of undefined

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-recordeditform

I have simple lightning component that is using [`lighting:recordEditForm`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_recordEditForm.htm) and input fields on Quote object. This quote object is custom, as CPQ is implemented in the system.

**Component**

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >       
    <lightning:recordEditForm recordId="{! v.recordId }" objectApiName="Quote">
        <div class="slds-box slds-theme_default">
            <lightning:messages />
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="BDM_Approved__c" />
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="BDM_Approval_Comments__c" />
            <lightning:button class="slds-m-top_small" variant="brand" type="submit" name="update" label="Update" />
        </div>
    </lightning:recordEditForm>
</aura:component>
```

**Error**

I am receiving an error when I test the component

> Cannot read property 'defaultRecordTypeId' of undefined

Recordtype: I don't have any record types on Quote object and documentation clearly specifies, `recordTypeId` attribute is **required** only if I have multiple record types on the object.

`recordTypeId` The ID of the record type, which is required if youcreated multiple record types but don't have a default.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I thought it would be helpful for someone who runs into this issue, would find solace here.

I needed to use exact **ObjectApiName** of the object, i.e. **`SBQQ__Quote__c`** and that worked fine.

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >       
    <lightning:recordEditForm recordId="{! v.recordId }" objectApiName="SBQQ__Quote__c">
        <div class="slds-box slds-theme_default">
            <lightning:messages />
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="BDM_Approved__c" />
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="BDM_Approval_Comments__c" />
            <lightning:button class="slds-m-top_small" variant="brand" type="submit" name="update" label="Update" />
        </div>
    </lightning:recordEditForm>
</aura:component>
```

Two interesting take-aways from this

1. As opposed to an earlier question posted **[What is the use of ObjectApiName](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/202707/what-is-the-use-of-objectapiname-in-lightningrecordviewform)**, here I needed to use exact Api name of the object, I guess since there is already standard object `Quote` that might be confusing for the system.
2. `BDM_Approval_Comments__c` is a long text area field. [`lighting:input`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_input.htm) has no support for text area and yet **it is working fine**.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is because system cann't understand value in objectApiName so if you are using any custom object use full api name with '__c'. 
Otherwise, for standard objects like account and contact, just use Account and Contact in ObjectApiName and it will work.

Thanks,